# parsing and applying conditional element on key value pair in typescript

Tags: json, typescript, ionic2, key-value

I am doing an Ionic App with typescript. 
I have some error condition as response from REST API, 
I did

```
err._body
```

and it gives me

```
{"reason":"invalid_token"}
```

but when I do

```
err._body.reason
```

or

```
err._body.get("reason")
```

it gives undefined value.

I did JSON stringify and parse as well, no luck,

How to parse this and get the value so that I can apply specific processing for this.

Comment: error => {
  this.error = true;
  console.log(error.json()); //gives the object object
  this.showError(error.json());
}

Answer (score 0):

First try to do

```
console.log(typeof err._body);
```

so we can be sure what the type of that is. If it's a `string`, you should do

```
let errorObj = JSON.parse(err._body);

// And then...

let errorMsg = errorObj.reason // or errorObj["reason"] as well
```

If it's an `Object`, you can skip the `parse()` part and just use it like this:

```
let errorMsg = err._body.reason // or err._body["reason"]
```